# How to verify contract programmatically?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I'm using NextJS, Hardhat, TS, and working in the ZkSync network. I have a smart contract factory. Users can click a button on the website, pass arguments, and a new smart contract will be created with the specified values.

Then I get the contract address and can easily verify it by running the command:

```
npx hardhat verify <contract-address> "arg1" "arg2"
```

However, since users create contracts, I need an automated verification process. I found a solution:

```
const verificationId = await hre.run("verify:verify", {
  address: contractAddress,
  contract: contractFullyQualifedName,
  constructorArguments: [...]
});
```

I can create a task in Hardhat to run it, receive the arguments, and verify the contract. But here's where I encounter difficulties. As far as I understand, I can't add this function to the frontend because Hardhat only works in a Node.js environment.

Therefore, as a possible solution, I need to create an api/verify folder and send POST requests there to initiate the verification task, passing the necessary arguments in the request body. But doesn't that seem like a workaround to you?

I tried to create an API:

```
// verify.ts
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { run } from "hardhat";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { contractAddress, contractFullyQualifedName, constructorArguments } = req.body;

  try {

    const verificationId = await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      contract: contractFullyQualifedName,
      constructorArguments: constructorArguments,
    });

    res.status(200).json({ verificationId });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to verify contract." });
  }
}
```

And here's how I send the requests:

```
const handleVerifyContract = async () => {
    const contractAddress = "0x1234567890...";
    const constructorArguments = [
      10000000000000000,
      "0x987654321...",
    ];

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/verify", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          contractAddress: contractAddress,
          price: constructorArguments[0],
          owner: constructorArguments[1],
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setVerificationId(data.verificationId);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to verify contract.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

But I'm receiving a 500 error response that I don't understand how to fix.

Overall, maybe you know and can provide some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Try `console.error(error.message)` to find out more.  I don't know why you don't see this when printing error object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it under hardhat also.  I've used your code or something very similar to it in my project at https://github.com/oehm-smith/alchemy-eth-week7-MintGovernance in the file `scripts/0a.verify.js` and I run it with:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/0a.verify.js --network goerli
```

And for completeness sake, that script looks like:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = hre;
const { getContracts } = require("./utils")
const { toUtf8Bytes, keccak256, parseEther } = ethers.utils;

require("dotenv").config();

async function verify() {
    // const deployValues = await deployFixture();
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const { governor, token, governorAddress, tokenAddress } = await getContracts();

    try {
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: governorAddress,
            constructorArguments: [
                tokenAddress
            ]
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.error(e.message)
        }
    }
    try {
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: tokenAddress,
            constructorArguments: [
                governorAddress
            ]
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.error(e.message)
        }
    }
}

verify().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Now I guess the question you really have is "How do I run verify as part of a service".  And that is a good one as I'm just learning all this and hadn't yet had to think about that.

I will have to do research but off the top of my head I'd think you could start the service under hard-hat. You could just make it a micro-service and that is all it does.  Some Express or NestJS app started in this way.  I'm sure others have written about this ... but I can't see any immediate answers.

So sorry, this is only 1/2 an answer but should be a good leg up for you.

Comment: In thinking about it, and having now undertaken more development, I don't know I'd want to programmatically deploy and verify contracts as part of a service.  Because I want the `artifact` to be available to my front-end code I want to compile and deploy as a separate step always.  I can see that there could be use cases for creating contracts in a service.  in which case I think you should just be able to run hardhat in a container inside that service.